# StreamReader object got automatically disposed

Tags: c#, .net, exception, streamreader

I have faced a weird error.

I need to download some files from excel which are uploaded on today. Files on FTP have the timestamp appeded with the filename.
The code is as below:

```
FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strUrl);
ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strUserName, strPassword);
ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();


string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
{
    if (line.Contains(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")))
    {
        strDownloadFilesName.Add(line);
        downloadPath = downloadPath + line;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(downloadPath, FileMode.Create);
        int ReadCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        while (ReadCount > 0)
        {
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, ReadCount);
            ReadCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        string ResponseDescription = response.StatusDescription;
        //fs.Close();
        //responseStream.Close();
    }

    line = streamReader.ReadLine();

}
```

in the above code, once the if condition is true then after some iterations,

```
line = streamReader.ReadLine();
```

this line throws the error of:

```
Cannot access dispose object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
```

Please help me out with it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even with `fs.Close` and `responseStream.Close` commented out?

Comment: yes even commenting it.

Comment: I could be wrong but maybe there is a Problem if you use the  readline Method before the loop

Comment: I'm slightly concerned that you have both `streamReader` and `responseStream` "in play" here - they are both talking to the same underlying stream; I'd wager that is a part of the problem here...

Comment: you are reading from ftp stream, and doing lengthy process in between. most of ftp servers are configured to disconnect the inactive client after some time of inactivity. Try reading the entire ftp content first and then parse/download..

Comment: You can also set the request timeout

Comment: btw, *not* so critical re the error (but: re good practice): there are a lot of `IDisposable` objects here that should be wrapped in `using` - `response`, and whichever of the two stream-based APIs you choose to keep (you can't keep both, that makes no sense), and `fs`

Comment: what is the file format here, and why are you expecting multiple records (`while`) ? the code suggests it is a single line of text-based data containing the path, and the rest of the stream contents (to the EOF) is the payload for that file... so... how cold we expect another read-line to work at the end of that?

Comment: @MarcGravell The stream contains list of files. so i am using while to test a condition on the files to get the required files only from FTP.

Comment: @KunalKakkad but you are reading from `responseStream`, to the EOF, via the inner `while` loop; you can only possibly process 1 file like this... If you read from a stream to the end: *you're now at the end of the stream*

Comment: @KunalKakkad also note that you're probably also corrupting that single file that works, because the text-based stream-reader will buffer data by over-reading; that means you're probably also missing the *start* of the first file when you write it to disk

Comment: @MarcGravell: Ok. if is it so then the response which i am getting is already having multiple files and i need multiple files too. Now how to handle such thing to get the multiple files from FTP

Comment: @KunalKakkad if a single stream contains multiple payloads, then you need to establish a protocol for describing how each is framed. In the case of binary data (which appears to be the case here), this typically means a length-prefix of an integer in some pre-agreed layout (for example, little-endian fixed 4 bytes). But only you can tell us what it is in your specific case.,

Comment: @MarcGravell: Going with the simpler tone, The response contain only xls files. And no directory is available over the FTP response. So i need to download multiple files from that FTP response to my local directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a part of solution of the problem, I need to make different calls to achieve it instead of looping it by calling single time.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something as below,

```
 using (StreamReader streamread = new StreamReader(responseStream))
 {
      string responseString = streamread.ReadToEnd();
 }
```

So instead of reading one line at a time, read the entire stream at once.
hope it helps.

Comment: The code shown clearly reads the payload as binary; reading the entire thing via a text-based reader would corrupt the contents instantly.

Comment: actually every line of stream contains a different file name. And out of that i only want to have the files which satisfies my condition and then need to save that file to local directory. how does reading the everything at once will help me out?

Comment: I thought of reading the entire stream in a string and split the entire string by a new line.

Comment: @KunalKakkad if "every line of stream" contains file **names**... where are the *contents*?

Comment: the path which is specified in FTP request will be reverting back just the list of file names as a part of response. But everytime only the single file is getting downloaded instead of multiple. Also single file is generating perfect.